# ASP Menu driving me insane

Tags: dynamic, asp-classic, menu

I am trying to create a menu using ASP (I have never used ASP before, im a PHP man) using values stored in a database.

basically the html layout i want is as such:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
   <li class="sub-menu-li">Test</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I need to loop around the root menu items rs("AD_Level") which is equal to 0 for root objects, then inside that loop, lop around anything that has the same parent id eg if the current record is AD_Level =0 and AD_Parent=5 then loop around all items with AD_Parent 5 and AD_Level != 0 and insert the values into html and so on and so forth.

Please help! I am struggling with a new language and cannot see a way to do this without losing sanity

**Edit** *(Extracted from Comment by OP)*

```
while not rsAdmin.eof
  sPar = rsAdmin("ad_parent"
  if rsAdmin("AD_Level")=0 then
    while not rsAdmin2.eof
      if rsAdmin2("AD_Level")<>0 and rsAdmin2("ad_parent")=sPar and rsAdmin2("AD_Sec_Level")=>2 then
        response.write rsAdmin("AD_Menu")
      end if
      rsAdmin2.movenext
    wend
  end if 
  '' # if not rsAdmin.eof then sPar=rsAdmin("AD_parent") rsAdmin.movenext
wend
```

that is my code

Comment: Is this ASP.NET or ASP?  In any case show us the code you have -- we need some context.

Comment: while not rsAdmin.eof
 sPar = rsAdmin("ad_parent")
 if rsAdmin("AD_Level")=0 then
  while not rsAdmin2.eof
   if rsAdmin2("AD_Level")<>0 and rsAdmin2("ad_parent")=sPar and rsAdmin2("AD_Sec_Level")=>2 then
    response.write rsAdmin("AD_Menu")
   end if
    rsAdmin2.movenext
   wend
 end if
   'if not rsAdmin.eof then sPar=rsAdmin("AD_parent")
rsAdmin.movenext
wend


that is my code

Comment: @simplesimon:  SO encourages you to revisit and edit your question adding details as you think of them and/or are requested from others comments.  Code especailly does not format well in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Surely this is an obvious case for using recursion, just providing psuedo-code below since I can't really understand your menu structure very well from your code so I've not attempted to put it directly into ASP code:

```
For Each MenuItem at with Level=0
    Display the Menu Text (if applicable)
    Call GenerateSubMenu(MenuItem.ID)
Next

Function GenerateSubMenu(ID)
    For Each MenuItem with Parent=ID
        Display the Menu Text (if applicable)
        Call GenerateSubMenu(MenuItem.ID)
    Next
End Function
```